# Why objects lost in session?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, apache2.4

I am trying to redirect http to https on apache2.4.10 and ubuntu 14.04 with tomcat 8 as servlet container at backend.
  The redirect configured in 000-default.conf and ssl configured in default-ssl.conf.
  The certificates and redirect seems working, but objects stored in the session after login are lost?

How could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your session cookie is probably not being rewritten properly, see e.g. ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain in the manual.